# MicroPython - is it compatible with gpiozero ?RPi.GPIO?

Tags: python, gpiozero

I'm making an IOT project for home automation, including a dozen of Rpi Zero-W using `Strech-Lite` operating syste, to control and report its Sensor and/ or relay's status.

I believe a ESP32 [Ebay link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ESP32-ESP32S-CP2102-Development-Board-2-4GHz-Dual-Mode-WiFi-Bluetooth-Antenna/201853283621?hash=item2eff64ad25:g:~HEAAOSwUoNaJ15-) would be much more reliable since it is a controller running code rather that a whole operating system as my current solution ( By the way micro:bit does not qualify since it lacks wifi ).

My question is - can I use `gpiozero` library ? since my code is based on it

Comment: The GPIO on a raspberry pi is used very differently than on ESP32 microcontrollers. Don't expect your code to work.

Comment: @KlausD. thank you- do you know that for sure ? do you know if RPi.GPIO will ?

Comment: In a mechanics world your question would be equivalent to: Can I use the power stearing from my car on my bicycle. To make it more clear: No, specialized RPi libraries will not work on your microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classes supported in MicroPython [here](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/pyb.html)